# PHP livewire displaying an object's property inside a form

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have a partially working code. I can display information from my livewire component but if my component has an object, I cannot display a property of that object.
See below I can display `$department` but I cannot display `$user->firstname`.

Is there a special way to retrieve an object property?
I tried: `wire:model="user.firstname"`

My livewire component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\User;

class EditUser extends Component
{
    public $userId;
    public $user;

    public $department='Training';

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.edit-user');
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->user = User::findOrFail($this->userId);
    }
}
```

My blade.php

```
        {{-- This section works --}}
         <div>
            {{ __('Update User Details') }}
            user_id: {{ $userId }}
            user_id: {{ $user->firstname }}
            department: {{ $department }}
        </div>

        {{-- This section DOES NOT WORK --}}
        <div>
            <x-label for="firstname" value="{{ __('First Name') }}" />
            <x-input id="firstname" name="firstname" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" required autofocus
                autocomplete="firstname" wire:model="user.firstname"/>
        </div>


       {{-- This section works --}}
        <div class="mt-4">
            <x-label for="department" value="{{ __('Department') }}" />
            <x-input id="department" name="department" type="text" required autocomplete="department"
                wire:model.defer="department" />
        </div>
```

The department

Comment: Is that your entire view? Or does your blade-file contain more HTML?